# Connecting to Facebook Chat using SleekXMPP

Tags: python, xmpp, facebook-chat

I'm using this sample code to connect to Facebook Chat over XMPP:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sleekxmpp
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def session_start(event):
    chatbot.send_presence()
    print('Session started')
    chatbot.get_roster()

def message(msg):
    if msg['type'] in ('chat','normal'):
        print('msg received')
        print(msg['body'])

        msg.reply('Thanks').send()

jid = 'myusername@chat.facebook.com'
password = 'mypassword'
server = ('chat.facebook.com', 5222)

chatbot = sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP(jid,password)
chatbot.add_event_handler('session_start', session_start)
chatbot.add_event_handler('message', message)
chatbot.auto_reconnect = True
chatbot.connect(server)
chatbot.process(block=True)
```

Everything seems to be Ok, but when I run that code, I can't connect to Facebook server:

```
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.basexmpp:setting jid to myusername@chat.facebook.com
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.basexmpp:Loaded Plugin (RFC-6120)  STARTTLS Stream Feature
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.basexmpp:Loaded Plugin (RFC-6120)  Resource Binding Stream Feature
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.basexmpp:Loaded Plugin (RFC-3920)  Start Session Stream Feature
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.basexmpp:Loaded Plugin (RFC-6120)  SASL Stream Feature
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:Trying to connect to chat.facebook.com:5222
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:Connecting to chat.facebook.com:5222
ERROR:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:Could not connect to chat.facebook.com:5222. Socket Error #111: Connection refused
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:Trying to connect to chat.facebook.com:5222
DEBUG:sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream:Waiting 1.97953654103 seconds before connecting.
...
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing everything correctly in your script. It appears to be a temporary issue on Facebook's end (as hinted by `Socket Error #111: Connection refused`). Testing against both master and develop branches of Sleek, your script connects and logs in fine for me.

Looking at the Facebook XMPP Developer Relations group, there haven't been any outage reports recently, so I'm not sure what the service situation currently is.

As an extra note, since you're dealing with Facebook, if you want to use the `X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM` authentication method, then you can set:

```
chatbot.credentials['api_key'] = '...API_KEY...'
chatbot.credentials['access_token'] = '...TOKEN...'
```

Don't forget that there is also the sleek@conference.jabber.org room if you need Sleek related help.

-- Lance

Comment: Well, I'm still unable to connect to `chat.facebook.com:5222`, it fails on every try. Any idea what might be wrong? Using Python 2.7.2+ with SleekXMPP 1.0 installed from pip.

Comment: Regarding `X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM` authentication method, I only need to put that lines on my code or I am missing something? I already have my API key and access token, but I don't know how to tell sleekxmpp to use that authentication method... Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Ok, to try to see where the problem is you can try manually testing using telnet: telnet chat.facebook.com 5222, and enter some characters and hit enter. You should get an error response back if you are able to connect to the chat server. I would expect the telnet command to fail saying it can't connect. Are you behind any firewalls that may prohibit connecting to facebook chat?

Comment: Yes, you only need to add those two lines to your script. Sleek will automatically try using X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM, and will fall back to DIGEST-MD5 if that information isn't correct or present. However, you will need to upgrade to using the develop branch version of Sleek for that; checking again it looks like I didn't have that feature ready in the 1.0 release.

Comment: Oh, realized that my `/etc/hosts` file was blocking `chat.facebook.com` domain, so weird! Thank you for the tips!
Switched to sleekxmpp 1.0.1-dev anyway, `X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM` authentication worked like a charm! Thanks for all the help!